# Why android popupwindow showAsDropDown offsetx is not effective?

Tags: android, android-layout, mobile

```
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(morebutton, xOffset, yOffset);
```

No matter the value of xOffset, the popup is on the right side of the screen display

```
final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(DashboardActivity.applicationContext);
                        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) DashboardActivity.applicationContext.getSystemService(
                                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
                        popupWindow.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        popupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        popupWindow.setContentView(view);
                        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(
                                android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(morebutton, **-220**, -40);
```

No matter what I set the value offsetX, he is on the right side of the screen display

Comment: What layout are you using ? Linear / Relative,..?

Answer (score 7):

`PopupWindow` tries to align your `contentView` to your `anchor`'s `Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START` (top left corner) by default. If there is no space left for your `contentView` it gets offset to fit on the screen, which is probably why it stays on your right side.

The following xOffset will align the `contentView` at your `anchor`'s top right corner:

```
view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
int xOffset = -(view.getMeasuredWidth() - morebutton.getWidth());

popupWindow.showAsDropDown(morebutton, xOffset, 0);
```

You might want something like:

```
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(morebutton, xOffset - 220, -40);
```